# Regular Expressions in Qt (QRegExp) [bad repetition syntax?]

Tags: regex, qt

I have written code below

```
QString patternStr = "\\{\\\\@\\\\.+?\\\\.+?\\\\\\}";
QRegExp rx(patternStr); 
QString content = "{\@\Bob\96\} {\@\Andy\1001484\} nice to see u";
bool match = rx.exactMatch(content);
if (match)
{
   qDebug()<<"match";
}
else
{
   qDebug()<<"not match "<<rx.errorString();
}
```

But got the error "bad repetition syntax", Can someone provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: Try `[{]\\\\@\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\[}]`. Also, `exactMatch` won't return true since it expects a full string match. Note that there are no lazy quantifiers in Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are no lazy quantifiers in Qt, and the `+?`  subpattern cannot be parsed correctly by the Qt regex engine.

Thus, I suggest using *negated character class* `[^\\]` in the pattern instead:

```
[{]\\\\@\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\[}]
```

I enclose the `{` and `}` into a character class so that you do not have to escape any of them.

Comment: Just FYI: I think you can use a [`QRegularExpression::InvertedGreedinessOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) flag (*The greediness of the quantifiers is inverted: `*`, `+`, `?`, `{m,n}`, etc. become lazy, while their lazy versions (`*?`, `+?`, `??`, `{m,n}?`, etc.) become greedy*) to use lazy matching in Qt with `"\\{\\\\@\\\\.+\\\\.+\\\\\\}"` pattern. However, it won't be efficient.